# Digital Ocean API v2 `userdata` callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback, electron

I'm writing and electron app that spins up a little proxy server using digital oceans api v2.

The code works, I would like a different way of knowing when to test the server rather than it being based on time, or weather the proxy is running or not, because sometimes it take 59 seconds to build the server, sometimes 65 seconds and sometimes 35 seconds. its just not very user friendly to have to wait all that extra time if the server has already finished.

So to get to the point, I am looking for maybe an err callback from the `userdata` that is run when creating a droplet.

Also i am already aware of checking

`cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

I had the thought of remotely SSHing the server and checking is the squid.conf had been updated or something similar, but that seems overly complex.

Anyone have an idea?

Or maybe have a file created as the last action and have my scripted checking if that file is there? how would i go about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that this is indeed not something that exists. There is no callback for the userdata you send to the new machine.

...in case anyone runs across this.

I solved my issue by using a `settimeout` for 60seconds to give the scripts long enough to run.